# Get a list of editable fields in sharepoint list

Tags: development, 2007

What is a foolproof method of getting a list of fields that are editable by the user from the UI in a SharePoint list.

I tried getting the ShowInEditForm property, but in many cases, it returns NULL.

I tried this condition check,

```
listfield.Hidden != true && listfield.ReadOnlyField != true && listfield.FromBaseType != true
```

but that includes Attachment and Content Type Fields

Answer (score 2):

You can add this to your code

```
listfield.Type != SPFieldType.Attachments
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ShowInEditForm and the ShowInNewForm but check for the NULL.  Is it is different than NULL, use this value.  Else, try your condition check.

Answer (score 1):

There is a more, um, DETAILED answer here, but it seems top-heavy to me:

http://sandeepnakarmi.com.np/2010/06/sharepoint-lists-editable-fields/

I had this same problem today and found a more elegant answer, although Attachments seems to be a one-off fix.  You also need to keep in mind that you can hide user-editable fields yourself, and they will appear as Hidden = true. For my case, I want to list all user-serviceable fields, including ones I had hidden from the user.

This method returns true if the field given is a user-editable field:

```
private bool IsValidField(SPField objField)
{
  return (!objField.ReadOnlyField &&
    objField.CanToggleHidden &&
    objField.Type != SPFieldType.Attachments);
}
```

OK, just let me say that the code block formatting feature in this forum kicks ass.  I love it.

P.S. I realize this thread is almost a year old, so I presume the OP has found his answer or, as is usually the case, a work-around. I try to provide an answer to old threads when it relates to my current dilemna, as I figure someone else is going to search for the same problem as me, and it is better to have an answer in an old thread than none at all.